# Mink with Selenium2 : how to connect to selenium server?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, behat, mink, selenium-server

i'm trying to configure Behat tests with selenium server.

my behat.yml is:

```
default:
  paths:
    features: features
    bootstrap: %behat.paths.features%/bootstrap
extensions:
  Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
    base_url:  'http://prog.easyhospi.itg.crmsante.com/'
    default_session: 'selenium2'
    browser_name: 'firefox'
    selenium2:        
      wd_host: 'http://127.0.0.1:5555/wd/hub'             
      capabilities: { "browser": "firefox", "version": "29"}
```

i ran selenium server this way:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.41.0.jar -role hub
```

and then:

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,version=29,maxInstances=1
```

I have got the error message "Could not open connection"
What is missing?

Answer (score 1):

Capabilities of at least one node need to match capabilities requested from behat. Last time I used selenium grid, [I needed to set the version to an empty string](http://zalas.eu/running-behat-in-parallel-with-selenium-grid/), otherwise selenium could not match the browser version:

```
# behat.yml
default:
  extensions:
    Behat\MinkExtension\Extension:
      selenium2:
        capabilities:
          version: ''
```

Note that you don't need to run grid. In most cases it's sufficient to run selenium as a standalone server (this way no capabilities need to be configured):

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.25.0.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, sorry for that post, but Curl was missing... didn't see that requirement in the doc.

you are right, selenium grid is not needed, but my behat.yml matches: if i don't specify "default_session: 'selenium2'", i have an error about goutte.

thanks.